# How can I prevent VS Code to revert my changes on save?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code, text-editor

I have a file open in VS Code

[image]

As you can see on line 1, 5, and 6, there are errors.

When I hovered over them, I saw this message.

[image]

Then, I decided to fix them base on the error message suggested.

[image]

Now, the 3 errors are gone. BUT as soon as I hit **save**.

Those errors are coming back. My changes seem to be **reverted**.

---

I have this set in my `settings.json`

> "editor.formatOnSave": true

Any suggestions on how can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: Which TypeScript related extensions do you have installed?

Comment: How do I️ find out ?

Comment: Check the extensions panel.

Comment: I checked and couldn't find a setting in VS Code that leads to quotes being replaced automatically through formatting so I'm wondering if you've got an extension installed that does this.

Comment: You could try setting this to false (although that is the default):   // Turns auto fix on save on or off.
  "eslint.autoFixOnSave": false,  I would guess that esLint (do you have that extension installed?) is causing the problem (it is also built into vscode).  It has a rule about enforcing the consistent use of single or double quotes.  If the above setting doesn't help, let us know.

Comment: I tried `"eslint.autoFixOnSave": false` - same result. I saved file reverted back again.

Comment: @FabianLauer : *Check the extensions panel.* <-- where is that in the VS Code application ?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_browse-and-install-extensions

Comment: @FabianLauer : What should I search for in there ? Is there a specific one you want me to search for ?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't change either `editor.formatOnSave` to `false` nor disable `tslint` as the other answers suggest. They are both very good tools to use. Although you might consider switching from `tslint` to `eslint`, as [`ts-lint` will be deprecated](https://medium.com/palantir/tslint-in-2019-1a144c2317a9).

Your problem is actually that `tslint` wants to use single quotes and your VSCode is configured to use double quotes. So when you format your code automatically, VSCode will use double quotes. You can change this with this simple setting in `settings.json`:

```
"typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single",
```

Answer (score -1):

Disable Angular essential extension or disable tslint extension.

[image: disable angularessentials]

Comment: I wouldn't disable `tslint`, as it's a very useful tool. We just need to tell VSCode to use the right quotes when formatting. See my answer.